# How to rewrite $\cos2x$ in terms of $\frac{1-\sin x}{ 1+\sin x}$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Would you please tell me how to rewrite $\cos2x$ in terms of

$$\frac{1-\sin(x)}{ 1+\sin(x)}$$
I had rewritten $\cos(2x)$ in terms of $\tan(x)$. But no results!
I did this job! Here:
$$\cos2x=\frac{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{ \cos(x)+\sin(x) }$$

Comment: If you got $\cos(2x)=1$ (which is the fraction you wrote), you made a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

If $\dfrac{1-\sin x}{1+\sin x}=y,\sin x=?$

Now use $\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

$$\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x)$$

Comment: Would you explain your hint more bro?